# radio button show unselected but can't be click in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, click, runtime-error

I have a form as below, and I want to click portrait mode, but I got error, then I found that I can show it in unselected status so that I think it is visible, why did I got error?

```
radio = browser.find_element_by_id("orientation_landscape_right")
print(radio.is_selected())
radio = browser.find_element_by_id("orientation_portrait")
print(radio.is_selected())
radio.click()
browser.find_element_by_name("commit").submit()
```

HTML:

```
<form class="img-orientation-form" action="/account/orientation" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="orientation" id="orientation_landscape_right" value="landscape_right" class="img-orientation-radio landscape-right" checked="checked"><span>(default)</span>
    <input type="radio" name="orientation" id="orientation_upside_down" value="upside_down" class="img-orientation-radio upside-down">
    <input type="radio" name="orientation" id="orientation_landscape_left" value="landscape_left" class="img-orientation-radio landscape-left">
    <input type="radio" name="orientation" id="orientation_portrait" value="portrait" class="img-orientation-radio portrait">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Output and Error:

```
True
False
radio.click()
self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated",
```

Comment: Can you try `print(len(browser.find_elements_by_id("orientation_portrait")))` to ensure that there is only one element with this id

Comment: There is len in my python36, why? by the way, only radio has issue, submit is OK, then I checked source there is only one id.

Comment: Can you share page `URL`?

Comment: http://ipcamera.userlocal.jp/photos/latest with 502241/7116

Answer (score 0):

This is timing issue: target radio-button is initially in `DOM`, but it is invisible and you're trying to click it before it actually becomes visible. So you need to wait some time for a visibility of element:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[normalize-space(.)="Settings"]').click() # To expand drop-down menu
wait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "orientation-button"))).click() # Click on "Image orientation" link
wait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "orientation_portrait"))).click() # wait for radio-button visibility + click
```

Comment: I got the same error, even I add time to 100! but if I try code  browser.execute_script("arguments[0].checked = true;", radio), it is no error, but image is still in landscape mode, do you know why?

Comment: I'm quite sure that you cannot get the same error when clicking radio-button. Do you make any actions to expand drop-down "Settings"?

Comment: I move mouse over settings thend clicked on change orientation, then clicked on modal dialog and submit button, that's all.

Comment: Do you see that modal window with radio-buttons is opened or you use `PhantomJS`? Which element is not visible with my code? Can you share complete log?

Comment: Yeah, I am using PhantomJS, because code created by JavaScript.

Comment: Also clarify what you mean `I am using PhantomJS, because code created by JavaScript`? Which code created by `JavaScript`? Why you think that your code won't work on, for example, `Firefox` or `Chrome`?

Comment: All images url created by JavaScript. Then when I run your answer, I got error as below:     wait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "orientation-button"))).click()  link
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: I still see no reason to use headless browser instead of simple `chromedriver` or `geckodriver`- the way how media generated should not affect on browser performance... But if you want to use `PhantomJS`, you can try `browser.get_screenshot_as_file('/path/to/file.png')` to check whether page appears as you expect

Comment: Sorry that I am new for those topic, at first I used BeautifulSoup to scrape page, then I found those pages are created by JavaScript and I found PhantomJS can be used for it so I used it. By your message, chromedriver or gecko driver are both can scrape page created by JavaScript? About that image, I can browser.get_screenshot_as_file in landscape format, but I want to save them in Portrait mode so that I want to change orientation....

Comment: Yes, you can use `Chrome`, `Firefox`, `IE`, etc to work with target page. I mean you can use `get_screenshot_as_file()` to get current state of the page and check whether it really looks like you expect... as, for example, `Setting` button could be absent or drop-down could not be opened...